# PlayOrm Cassandra Seeds

Tags: playorm

I am trying to specify IP address of the "Seeds" parameter and am getting an exception:

```
You must specify a comma delimited list of seeds OR 'localhost:9160' as the seed
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
String seeds = "192.168.100.131:9160";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, there is a new feature where you can set the consistency level so if you pass in one or more nodes will not matter so you can do what you want know.  The property is Bootstrap.CASSANDRA_DEFAULT_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL and generally you set it to "CL_QUORUM"

Dean

Comment: I forgot to mention, on RF=3 and singlenode, you would want to set this to CL_ONE instead which allows you to grow the cluster from one to three and switch from CL_ONE to CL_QUOROM at a later time.  or you could use RF=1 and CL_QUOROM.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one node cassandra's are tricky.  First, PlayOrm does RF=3 by default always and for one node only, it does CL=ONE by default as CL=QUOROM fails on single nodes :(.  This allows you to add more cassandra's later and have RF=3 and CL then changes to QUOROM as a default.

A very quick work around is to tunnel like so

```
ssh -L9160:localhost:9160 <username>@192.168.100.131
```

File a ticket on github though and we can try to make this better.  We need to basically detect whether they are doing a single node or multi-node cassandra to determine the Consitency Level.  We need to think about it as we are creating an astyanax with defaults BUT we sort of want to use astyanax to find that information but we can't use astyanax until we configure a default CL....catch 22 here.  so we ended up just using the seeds list.

How about this...file a ticket where users must feed in a value in a property file of SINGLE_NODE in this case or we will still error out and we can explain that in the error.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Thanks Dean, I had no time to test the solution, but I will try it in the near future.